# What is the normalized database form for these 3 tables?

Tags: sql, database-design, normalization

So I have three tables and subsequently three models as well:

```
Company (table: companies)
Person (table: people)
Address (table: addresses)
```

How to connect these together, considering that each Person or Company can have multiple addressess, but since the addresses are in the same format I'd like to use one single 'addresses' table, so dealing/managin addresses can be done trough a single model?

Because this structure:

```
companies(id, name, ...)
people(id,name, ... )
addresses(id, foreign_id, foreign_model, ...)
```

Seems a bit out of place for me. basically this is the current sructure now. The 'foreign_model' field is a string which specifies which model the address belongs to (i.e. Company or Person).

All this under Cakephp, but I have many problems with this structure, what should I use instead?

Comment: I think you need more tables since you have 'many'-relationship. You could have a CompanyAdresses table with keys to Company and Address and the same for PersonAdresses.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, this is indeed what I thought first but I really tried to avoid it. I mean we could add new entities which have addresses and then we need to add a connection table each time?

Comment: np, yes there will be one row for each company adress combination.

Comment: are you going to connect something else to a company or person? example sell an item to a company or person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how abt this:

```
companies(id, name, address_id,..)
people   (id,name, address_id,... )
addresses(id,... )
```

Both companies and people  point to the address table for their  address.
Here you dont have to store any duplicate addresses if any

**EDIT**: If  both companies and people can have many addresses

Then keep a mapping table

```
companies(id, name,..)
people   (id,name, ... )
addresses(id,... )

Address_map(id,address_id,type)
```

Where type says whether its a company or a people

id --> either companyid or poepleid

Comment: Hey Joe thanks but both companies and people can have many addresses (like a company has many addresses you ship products to etc.) so basically this is a one-to-many connection.